Can the operating voltage be slighly above the reverse stand-off but well below breakdown?
I'm aware (also from this and this questions) that below the reverse stand-off voltage the TVS diode has no effect, and above the breakdown it begins to conduct.
In my design I have a quite tight constraint (or perhaps I'm not able to design it properly). The input voltage can reach a maximum of 16.8V and I need a maximum clamp below 28V.
I selected a SMCJ16A and it has the following parameters:

reverse stand-off voltage: 16.0 V
breakdown voltage: 17.80..19.70 V
maximum clamp voltage: 26.0 V

By the way, I know I can use the SMCJ17A that has Vr = 17 V but it also have a Vc = 27.8 V very close to the maximum ratings of one component I have to protect.
Hence my question: can I safely operate my circuit at 16.8 V even if the Vr of the TVS is 16.0 V?

You haven't stated what the peak surge/pulse current is so, how can you make a decision? Maybe read this also: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/705791/tvs-diode-current-flow-at-breakdown/705810#705810

@Andyaka, honestly I don't know how to estimate the ESD peak current

The ESD generator (or surge generator) has a defined output impedance. That defined output impedance sets the peak current. If it's ESD than any line capacitance will significantly reduce the peak current into the TVS as well. It boils down to drawing a circuit and then working out what the current into the TVS is and, if it's significantly less than the peak surge current in the data sheet then the peak clamping voltage will also be less.

@Andyaka got it thanks, I was thinking about a real ESD, not the generator used during the tests!

All ESD testing uses a generator so....

Mark, if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Consider the standard laboratory ESD surge generator as the basis for making a judgement on what TVS to use. Here's one that simulates the human body discharge: -

Image from Designing ESD Protection Circuits.
So, if the peak ESD voltage is (say) 16 kV (a fairly normal requirement) with the 1500 Ω output resistor, the peak current can be no more than 11 amps.
This means that the 17 volt TVS diode will be nowhere near clamping to 27.6 volts at 54.4 amps because it's only seeing an 11 amp surge: -

The TVS diode will not see more than than 11 amps so, you could pick a smaller part and get a more inexpensive design.

You can use 16V part, at 16V also there will be some leakage current in nano amp range across the TVS. Mostly the breakdown voltage will be measured at which the current across TVS will be 1mA. If you see a V-I characteristics graph of a TVS diode, you can understand that at 16V, the current will be less (nano amps in most cases) and it will gradually increases to 1mA when the voltage reaches the breakdown voltage. So you can use the part with 16V reverse standoff for 16.8V, but there will be a high leakage current compared to 16V, in hundreds of nano amps.
You can go with 17V part if your maximum surge current is less than 54.4A. The maximum clamping voltage 27.8V will be at this surge current. If the surge current is less, the clamping voltage also reduces.
